Flutter Native ads are sometimes displayed and sometimes not. [Native Template] Ad disappears
I am facing this issue on OnePlus 8T, Android 14, API 34
when the app starts I display the Ad on the Home Screen and that is working well but when I navigate to the other page where I place the Ad that one is making problems Sometimes it shows, and sometimes it does not.
However, the Ad is clickable, so each time I tap on the white space, it opens the advertiser's link.
Here you can see the Screen Shots
Home Page
>>>>>>>>>>>>>See 1st Image here
Next Page  where ad disappeared
>>>>>>>>>>>>>See 2nd Image here
I have searched for this issue and found some repositories on GitHub but didn't find any solution.
Here you can see the repositories:
>>>>>>>GitHub Link 1
>>>>>>>GitHub Link 2

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I can't upload images directly here.
But I have already cleared my problem. the screen shots and links are given

i face the same issue. Did you find a solution?

i am still looking to it, didnt find the solution yet

If anyone need help, i found a way for it to show. I notice that if i touch input or hold any button, ... native ad (currently transparent/ not show) will appear so i add some changes to the code.
After I setState the native ad then i delayed a bit and setState trigger which affect the container
  listener: NativeAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          if (!mounted) {
            ad.dispose();
            return;
          }
          setState(() {
            ifFailed = false;
            _nativeAd = ad as NativeAd;
          });

          Future.delayed(
            const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            () {
              setState(() {
                trigger = 0.000001;
              });
            },
          );



   Container(
    color: AppColor.white,
    padding:
        EdgeInsets.only(top: trigger.toDouble()),
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minWidth: 320, // minimum recommended width
        minHeight: 90, // minimum recommended height
        maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        maxHeight: 140,
      ),
      child: _nativeAd == null
          ? loadingNativeAd()
          : AdWidget(ad: _nativeAd!),
    ),
  ),

Sorry for my english and it's my first time comment too. Hope this help.

let me try this way
